# How to find occurrence of words from a log file with pyspark RDD

Tags: pyspark, rdd

I have a log file. I have read the file and converted in rdd. I want to count the number of times 'server_name' is present in the file.

Original log file I have -

```
from pyspark.context import SparkContext
from pyspark.sql.context import SQLContext
from pyspark.sql.session import SparkSession
   
sc = SparkContext()
sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)
spark = SparkSession(sc)
base_df = spark.read.text("/content/fsm-20210817.logs")

base_df_rdd = base_df.rdd

server_list = ['nginx-ingress-controller-5b6697898-zqxl4','cert-manager-5695c78d49-q9s9j']

for i in server_list:
  res = textFile.rdd.map(lambda x: x[0].split(' ').count(i)).sum()
  print(i,res)
```

I'm getting output as -

```
nginx-ingress-controller-5b6697898-zqxl4 0
cert-manager-5695c78d49-q9s9j 0
```

I have base_df_rdd as-

```
[Row(value='{"log":{"offset":5367960,"file":{"path":"/var/log/containers/cert-manager-5695c78d49-q9s9j_cert-manager_cert-manager-cf5af9cbaccdccd8f637d0ba7313996b1cfc0bab7b25fe9f157953918016ac84.log"}},"stream":"stderr","message":"E0817 00:00:00.144379       1 sync.go:183] cert-manager/controller/challenges \\"msg\\"=\\"propagation check failed\\" \\"error\\"=\\"wrong status code \'404\', expected \'200\'\\" \\"dnsName\\"=\\"prodapi.fsmbuddy.com\\" \\"resource_kind\\"=\\"Challenge\\" \\"resource_name\\"=\\"prodapi-fsmbuddy-tls-cert-vtvdq-1471208926-2451592135\\" \\"resource_namespace\\"=\\"default\\" \\"resource_version\\"=\\"v1\\" \\"type\\"=\\"HTTP-01\\" ","@timestamp":"2021-08-17T00:00:00.144Z","ecs":{"version":"1.0.0"},"cloud":{"instance":{"id":"i-06c596f469bcf9b4a"},"region":"ap-south-1","provider":"aws","availability_zone":"ap-south-1b","machine":{"type":"t3a.large"}},"input":{"type":"container"},"@version":"1","host":{"architecture":"x86_64","os":{"codename":"Core","version":"7 (Core)","name":"CentOS Linux","kernel":"4.14.186-146.268.amzn2.x86_64","platform":"centos","family":"redhat"},"hostname":"ip-192-168-18-105.ap-south-1.compute.internal","containerized":false,"name":"ip-192-168-18-105.ap-south-1.compute.internal"},"tags":["beats_input_codec_plain_applied","_grokparsefailure"],"agent":{"version":"7.2.0","type":"filebeat","ephemeral_id":"af246a38-d99d-43ab-849b-cf25288dd6c1","hostname":"ip-192-168-18-105.ap-south-1.compute.internal","id":"9631683c-b8fc-40d8-9e28-f80f5fa3cc2c"},"kubernetes":{"node":{"name":"ip-192-168-18-105.ap-south-1.compute.internal"},"container":{"name":"cert-manager"},"labels":{"helm_sh/chart":"cert-manager-v1.0.1","app_kubernetes_io/component":"controller","app_kubernetes_io/managed-by":"Tiller","pod-template-hash":"5695c78d49","app_kubernetes_io/instance":"cert-manager","app_kubernetes_io/name":"cert-manager","app":"cert-manager"},"pod":{"uid":"0be2ef9e-f2ee-4d40-b74b-17734527d78c","name":"cert-manager-5695c78d49-q9s9j"},"replicaset":{"name":"cert-manager-5695c78d49"},"namespace":"cert-manager"}}'),
 Row(value='{"log":{"offset":1946553,"file":{"path":"/var/log/containers/fsm-backend-cron-prod-6bd6459455-p9p49_default_fsm-backend-cron-prod-51838c21c82b0a19b713bf028da7418f9885fd29b606e5b9912c1c66f6c3046a.log"}},"stream":"stdout","message":"Inside user information updation cron: 2021-08-17T00:00:00.001Z","@timestamp":"2021-08-17T00:00:00.001Z","ecs":{"version":"1.0.0"},"cloud":{"instance":{"id":"i-06c596f469bcf9b4a"},"region":"ap-south-1","availability_zone":"ap-south-1b","provider":"aws","machine":{"type":"t3a.large"}},"input":{"type":"container"},"@version":"1","host":{"architecture":"x86_64","os":{"codename":"Core","version":"7 (Core)","name":"CentOS Linux","kernel":"4.14.186-146.268.amzn2.x86_64","platform":"centos","family":"redhat"},"hostname":"ip-192-168-18-105.ap-south-1.compute.internal","containerized":false,"name":"ip-192-168-18-105.ap-south-1.compute.internal"},"tags":["beats_input_codec_plain_applied","_grokparsefailure"],"agent":{"version":"7.2.0","type":"filebeat","ephemeral_id":"af246a38-d99d-43ab-849b-cf25288dd6c1","hostname":"ip-192-168-18-105.ap-south-1.compute.internal","id":"9631683c-b8fc-40d8-9e28-f80f5fa3cc2c"},"kubernetes":{"node":{"name":"ip-192-168-18-105.ap-south-1.compute.internal"},"container":{"name":"fsm-backend-cron-prod"},"labels":{"pod-template-hash":"6bd6459455","app":"fsm-backend-cron-prod"},"pod":{"uid":"c356f207-bc60-4974-9f8b-02ecfe87eaa0","name":"fsm-backend-cron-prod-6bd6459455-p9p49"},"replicaset":{"name":"fsm-backend-cron-prod-6bd6459455"},"namespace":"default"}}'),
 Row(value='{"log":{"offset":1946687,"file":{"path":"/var/log/containers/fsm-backend-cron-prod-6bd6459455-p9p49_default_fsm-backend-cron-prod-51838c21c82b0a19b713bf028da7418f9885fd29b606e5b9912c1c66f6c3046a.log"}},"stream":"stdout","message":"\\u001B[0;36mMongoose:\\u001B[0m orders.find({ orderStatus: \\u001B[32m\'success\'\\u001B[39m, orderDate: { \\u001B[32m\'$gte\'\\u001B[39m: new Date(\\"Mon, 16 Aug 2021 00:00:00 GMT\\") }}, { projection: {} })","@timestamp":"2021-08-17T00:00:00.002Z","ecs":{"version":"1.0.0"},"cloud":{"instance":{"id":"i-06c596f469bcf9b4a"},"region":"ap-south-1","availability_zone":"ap-south-1b","provider":"aws","machine":{"type":"t3a.large"}},"input":{"type":"container"},"@version":"1","host":{"os":{"codename":"Core","version":"7 (Core)","name":"CentOS Linux","kernel":"4.14.186-146.268.amzn2.x86_64","platform":"centos","family":"redhat"},"name":"ip-192-168-18-105.ap-south-1.compute.internal","hostname":"ip-192-168-18-105.ap-south-1.compute.internal","containerized":false,"architecture":"x86_64"},"tags":["beats_input_codec_plain_applied","_grokparsefailure"],"agent":{"version":"7.2.0","type":"filebeat","ephemeral_id":"af246a38-d99d-43ab-849b-cf25288dd6c1","hostname":"ip-192-168-18-105.ap-south-1.compute.internal","id":"9631683c-b8fc-40d8-9e28-f80f5fa3cc2c"},"kubernetes":{"node":{"name":"ip-192-168-18-105.ap-south-1.compute.internal"},"container":{"name":"fsm-backend-cron-prod"},"labels":{"pod-template-hash":"6bd6459455","app":"fsm-backend-cron-prod"},"pod":{"uid":"c356f207-bc60-4974-9f8b-02ecfe87eaa0","name":"fsm-backend-cron-prod-6bd6459455-p9p49"},"replicaset":{"name":"fsm-backend-cron-prod-6bd6459455"},"namespace":"default"}}'),
 Row(value='{"log":{"offset":1946955,"file":{"path":"/var/log/containers/fsm-backend-cron-prod-6bd6459455-p9p49_default_fsm-backend-cron-prod-51838c21c82b0a19b713bf028da7418f9885fd29b606e5b9912c1c66f6c3046a.log"}},"stream":"stdout","message":"******","@timestamp":"2021-08-17T00:00:00.003Z","ecs":{"version":"1.0.0"},"cloud":{"instance":{"id":"i-06c596f469bcf9b4a"},"region":"ap-south-1","availability_zone":"ap-south-1b","provider":"aws","machine":{"type":"t3a.large"}},"input":{"type":"container"},"@version":"1","host":{"architecture":"x86_64","name":"ip-192-168-18-105.ap-south-1.compute.internal","hostname":"ip-192-168-18-105.ap-south-1.compute.internal","os":{"codename":"Core","version":"7 (Core)","name":"CentOS Linux","kernel":"4.14.186-146.268.amzn2.x86_64","platform":"centos","family":"redhat"},"containerized":false},"tags":["beats_input_codec_plain_applied","_grokparsefailure"],"agent":{"version":"7.2.0","type":"filebeat","ephemeral_id":"af246a38-d99d-43ab-849b-cf25288dd6c1","hostname":"ip-192-168-18-105.ap-south-1.compute.internal","id":"9631683c-b8fc-40d8-9e28-f80f5fa3cc2c"},"kubernetes":{"node":{"name":"ip-192-168-18-105.ap-south-1.compute.internal"},"container":{"name":"fsm-backend-cron-prod"},"labels":{"pod-template-hash":"6bd6459455","app":"fsm-backend-cron-prod"},"pod":{"uid":"c356f207-bc60-4974-9f8b-02ecfe87eaa0","name":"fsm-backend-cron-prod-6bd6459455-p9p49"},"replicaset":{"name":"fsm-backend-cron-prod-6bd6459455"},"namespace":"default"}}'),
 Row(value='{"log":{"offset":1947032,"file":{"path":"/var/log/containers/fsm-backend-cron-prod-6bd6459455-p9p49_default_fsm-backend-cron-prod-51838c21c82b0a19b713bf028da7418f9885fd29b606e5b9912c1c66f6c3046a.log"}},"stream":"stdout","message":"\\u001B[0;36mMongoose:\\u001B[0m enrollments.find({ createdAt: { \\u001B[32m\'$gte\'\\u001B[39m: new Date(\\"Mon, 16 Aug 2021 23:00:00 GMT\\") }, isActive: { \\u001B[32m\'$ne\'\\u001B[39m: \\u001B[33mfalse\\u001B[39m }}, { projection: {} })","@timestamp":"2021-08-17T00:00:00.004Z","ecs":{"version":"1.0.0"},"cloud":{"instance":{"id":"i-06c596f469bcf9b4a"},"region":"ap-south-1","availability_zone":"ap-south-1b","provider":"aws","machine":{"type":"t3a.large"}},"input":{"type":"container"},"@version":"1","host":{"architecture":"x86_64","name":"ip-192-168-18-105.ap-south-1.compute.internal","hostname":"ip-192-168-18-105.ap-south-1.compute.internal","os":{"codename":"Core","version":"7 (Core)","name":"CentOS Linux","kernel":"4.14.186-146.268.amzn2.x86_64","platform":"centos","family":"redhat"},"containerized":false},"tags":["beats_input_codec_plain_applied","_grokparsefailure"],"agent":{"version":"7.2.0","type":"filebeat","ephemeral_id":"af246a38-d99d-43ab-849b-cf25288dd6c1","hostname":"ip-192-168-18-105.ap-south-1.compute.internal","id":"9631683c-b8fc-40d8-9e28-f80f5fa3cc2c"},"kubernetes":{"node":{"name":"ip-192-168-18-105.ap-south-1.compute.internal"},"container":{"name":"fsm-backend-cron-prod"},"labels":{"pod-template-hash":"6bd6459455","app":"fsm-backend-cron-prod"},"pod":{"uid":"c356f207-bc60-4974-9f8b-02ecfe87eaa0","name":"fsm-backend-cron-prod-6bd6459455-p9p49"},"replicaset":{"name":"fsm-backend-cron-prod-6bd6459455"},"namespace":"default"}}'),
 Row(value='{"log":{"offset":1947329,"file":{"path":"/var/log/containers/fsm-backend-cron-prod-6bd6459455-p9p49_default_fsm-backend-cron-prod-51838c21c82b0a19b713bf028da7418f9885fd29b606e5b9912c1c66f6c3046a.log"}},"stream":"stdout","message":"Currency data:{\\"result\\":\\"success\\",\\"documentation\\":\\"https://www.exchangerate-api.com/docs\\",\\"terms_of_use\\":\\"https://www.exchangerate-api.com/terms\\",\\"time_zone\\":\\"UTC\\",\\"time_last_update\\":1629072001,\\"time_next_update\\":1629158521,\\"base\\":\\"INR\\",\\"conversion_rates\\":{\\"INR\\":1,\\"AED\\":0.04946,\\"AFN\\":1.075,\\"ALL\\":1.3897,\\"AMD\\":6.63,\\"ANG\\":0.0241,\\"AOA\\":8.6508,\\"ARS\\":1.3046,\\"AUD\\":0.01829,\\"AWG\\":0.0241,\\"AZN\\":0.02285,\\"BAM\\":0.02239,\\"BBD\\":0.02693,\\"BDT\\":1.1405,\\"BGN\\":0.02239,\\"BHD\\":0.005063,\\"BIF\\":26.6861,\\"BMD\\":0.01347,\\"BND\\":0.0183,\\"BOB\\":0.09274,\\"BRL\\":0.07057,\\"BSD\\":0.01347,\\"BTN\\":1,\\"BWP\\":0.1497,\\"BYN\\":0.03361,\\"BZD\\":0.02693,\\"CAD\\":0.01688,\\"CDF\\":26.7409,\\"CHF\\":0.0124,\\"CLP\\":10.4188,\\"CNY\\":0.08741,\\"COP\\":51.9025,\\"CRC\\":8.3535,\\"CUC\\":0.01347,\\"CUP\\":0.3468,\\"CVE\\":1.2625,\\"CZK\\":0.2931,\\"DJF\\":2.3933,\\"DKK\\":0.08542,\\"DOP\\":0.7673,\\"DZD\\":1.8193,\\"EGP\\":0.2112,\\"ERN\\":0.202,\\"ETB\\":0.6076,\\"EUR\\":0.01145,\\"FJD\\":0.02801,\\"FKP\\":0.009749,\\"FOK\\":0.08542,\\"GBP\\":0.009749,\\"GEL\\":0.04202,\\"GGP\\":0.009749,\\"GHS\\":0.08076,\\"GIP\\":0.009749,\\"GMD\\":0.6996,\\"GNF\\":131.3706,\\"GTQ\\":0.1042,\\"GYD\\":2.8153,\\"HKD\\":0.1049,\\"HNL\\":0.3193,\\"HRK\\":0.08627,\\"HTG\\":1.2853,\\"HUF\\":4.086,\\"IDR\\":193.9741,\\"ILS\\":0.04382,\\"IMP\\":0.009749,\\"IQD\\":19.6346,\\"IRR\\":564.6901,\\"ISK\\":1.6955,\\"JMD\\":2.08,\\"JOD\\":0.009548,\\"JPY\\":1.4838,\\"KES\\":1.4694,\\"KGS\\":1.1411,\\"KHR\\":54.8746,\\"KID\\":0.01829,\\"KMF\\":5.6327,\\"KRW\\":15.6725,\\"KWD\\":0.004035,\\"KYD\\":0.01122,\\"KZT\\":5.7203,\\"LAK\\":129.023,\\"LBP\\":20.3005,\\"LKR\\":2.6874,\\"LRD\\":2.3085,\\"LSL\\":0.1992,\\"LYD\\":0.06092,\\"MAD\\":0.1208,\\"MDL\\":0.2391,\\"MGA\\":52.5738,\\"MKD\\":0.7039,\\"MMK\\":22.1546,\\"MNT\\":38.2846,\\"MOP\\":0.1081,\\"MRU\\":0.486,\\"MUR\\":0.5712,\\"MVR\\":0.2062,\\"MWK\\":10.9455,\\"MXN\\":0.2685,\\"MYR\\":0.05709,\\"MZN\\":0.8614,\\"NAD\\":0.1992,\\"NGN\\":5.5967,\\"NIO\\":0.4725,\\"NOK\\":0.1188,\\"NPR\\":1.6,\\"NZD\\":0.01915,\\"OMR\\":0.005178,\\"PAB\\":0.01347,\\"PEN\\":0.05494,\\"PGK\\":0.04721,\\"PHP\\":0.6817,\\"PKR\\":2.2107,\\"PLN\\":0.05259,\\"PYG\\":93.2322,\\"QAR\\":0.04902,\\"RON\\":0.05625,\\"RSD\\":1.3457,\\"RUB\\":0.988,\\"RWF\\":13.5649,\\"SAR\\":0.0505,\\"SBD\\":0.1072,\\"SCR\\":0.1964,\\"SDG\\":5.9863,\\"SEK\\":0.1167,\\"SGD\\":0.0183,\\"SHP\\":0.009749,\\"SLL\\":138.6306,\\"SOS\\":7.7848,\\"SRD\\":0.2883,\\"SSP\\":2.3945,\\"STN\\":0.2805,\\"SYP\\":16.9261,\\"SZL\\":0.1992,\\"THB\\":0.4511,\\"TJS\\":0.1521,\\"TMT\\":0.04714,\\"TND\\":0.03747,\\"TOP\\":0.03017,\\"TRY\\":0.1152,\\"TTD\\":0.09132,\\"TVD\\":0.01829,\\"TWD\\":0.3739,\\"TZS\\":31.209,\\"UAH\\":0.3591,\\"UGX\\":47.6167,\\"USD\\":0.01347,\\"UYU\\":0.5869,\\"UZS\\":144.1304,\\"VES\\":55690.0545,\\"VND\\":308.1789,\\"VUV\\":1.5055,\\"WST\\":0.03438,\\"XAF\\":7.5103,\\"XCD\\":0.03636,\\"XDR\\":0.009481,\\"XOF\\":7.5103,\\"XPF\\":1.3663,\\"YER\\":3.3625,\\"ZAR\\":0.1992,\\"ZMW\\":0.2599}}","@timestamp":"2021-08-17T00:00:00.813Z","ecs":{"version":"1.0.0"},"cloud":{"instance":{"id":"i-06c596f469bcf9b4a"},"region":"ap-south-1","provider":"aws","availability_zone":"ap-south-1b","machine":{"type":"t3a.large"}},"input":{"type":"container"},"@version":"1","host":{"architecture":"x86_64","name":"ip-192-168-18-105.ap-south-1.compute.internal","hostname":"ip-192-168-18-105.ap-south-1.compute.internal","os":{"codename":"Core","version":"7 (Core)","name":"CentOS Linux","kernel":"4.14.186-146.268.amzn2.x86_64","platform":"centos","family":"redhat"},"containerized":false},"tags":["beats_input_codec_plain_applied","_grokparsefailure"],"agent":{"version":"7.2.0","type":"filebeat","ephemeral_id":"af246a38-d99d-43ab-849b-cf25288dd6c1","hostname":"ip-192-168-18-105.ap-south-1.compute.internal","id":"9631683c-b8fc-40d8-9e28-f80f5fa3cc2c"},"kubernetes":{"node":{"name":"ip-192-168-18-105.ap-south-1.compute.internal"},"container":{"name":"fsm-backend-cron-prod"},"labels":{"pod-template-hash":"6bd6459455","app":"fsm-backend-cron-prod"},"pod":{"uid":"c356f207-bc60-4974-9f8b-02ecfe87eaa0","name":"fsm-backend-cron-prod-6bd6459455-p9p49"},"replicaset":{"name":"fsm-backend-cron-prod-6bd6459455"},"namespace":"default"}}'),
 Row(value='{"log":{"offset":1950159,"file":{"path":"/var/log/containers/fsm-backend-cron-prod-6bd6459455-p9p49_default_fsm-backend-cron-prod-51838c21c82b0a19b713bf028da7418f9885fd29b606e5b9912c1c66f6c3046a.log"}},"stream":"stdout","message":"\\u001B[0;36mMongoose:\\u001B[0m countries.find({ currency_code: \\u001B[32m\'INR\'\\u001B[39m }, { projection: {} })","@timestamp":"2021-08-17T00:00:01.026Z","ecs":{"version":"1.0.0"},"cloud":{"instance":{"id":"i-06c596f469bcf9b4a"},"region":"ap-south-1","provider":"aws","availability_zone":"ap-south-1b","machine":{"type":"t3a.large"}},"input":{"type":"container"},"@version":"1","host":{"architecture":"x86_64","name":"ip-192-168-18-105.ap-south-1.compute.internal","hostname":"ip-192-168-18-105.ap-south-1.compute.internal","containerized":false,"os":{"codename":"Core","version":"7 (Core)","name":"CentOS Linux","kernel":"4.14.186-146.268.amzn2.x86_64","platform":"centos","family":"redhat"}},"tags":["beats_input_codec_plain_applied","_grokparsefailure"],"agent":{"version":"7.2.0","type":"filebeat","ephemeral_id":"af246a38-d99d-43ab-849b-cf25288dd6c1","hostname":"ip-192-168-18-105.ap-south-1.compute.internal","id":"9631683c-b8fc-40d8-9e28-f80f5fa3cc2c"},"kubernetes":{"node":{"name":"ip-192-168-18-105.ap-south-1.compute.internal"},"container":{"name":"fsm-backend-cron-prod"},"labels":{"pod-template-hash":"6bd6459455","app":"fsm-backend-cron-prod"},"pod":{"uid":"c356f207-bc60-4974-9f8b-02ecfe87eaa0","name":"fsm-backend-cron-prod-6bd6459455-p9p49"},"replicaset":{"name":"fsm-backend-cron-prod-6bd6459455"},"namespace":"default"}}'),
 Row(value='{"log":{"offset":1950341,"file":{"path":"/var/log/containers/fsm-backend-cron-prod-6bd6459455-p9p49_default_fsm-backend-cron-prod-51838c21c82b0a19b713bf028da7418f9885fd29b606e5b9912c1c66f6c3046a.log"}},"stream":"stdout","message":"\\u001B[0;36mMongoose:\\u001B[0m countries.find({ currency_code: \\u001B[32m\'AED\'\\u001B[39m }, { projection: {} })","@timestamp":"2021-08-17T00:00:01.027Z","ecs":{"version":"1.0.0"},"cloud":{"instance":{"id":"i-06c596f469bcf9b4a"},"region":"ap-south-1","availability_zone":"ap-south-1b","provider":"aws","machine":{"type":"t3a.large"}},"input":{"type":"container"},"@version":"1","host":{"architecture":"x86_64","os":{"codename":"Core","version":"7 (Core)","name":"CentOS Linux","kernel":"4.14.186-146.268.amzn2.x86_64","platform":"centos","family":"redhat"},"hostname":"ip-192-168-18-105.ap-south-1.compute.internal","containerized":false,"name":"ip-192-168-18-105.ap-south-1.compute.internal"},"tags":["beats_input_codec_plain_applied","_grokparsefailure"],"agent":{"version":"7.2.0","type":"filebeat","ephemeral_id":"af246a38-d99d-43ab-849b-cf25288dd6c1","hostname":"ip-192-168-18-105.ap-south-1.compute.internal","id":"9631683c-b8fc-40d8-9e28-f80f5fa3cc2c"},"kubernetes":{"node":{"name":"ip-192-168-18-105.ap-south-1.compute.internal"},"container":{"name":"fsm-backend-cron-prod"},"labels":{"pod-template-hash":"6bd6459455","app":"fsm-backend-cron-prod"},"pod":{"uid":"c356f207-bc60-4974-9f8b-02ecfe87eaa0","name":"fsm-backend-cron-prod-6bd6459455-p9p49"},"replicaset":{"name":"fsm-backend-cron-prod-6bd6459455"},"namespace":"default"}}')],
```

Server_names are there in the log file but I'm getting count as 0. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using pyspark sql functions:

Split your string on the substring(server name in your case) that you are trying to count and `length of the array value - 1` would be the actual count of the substring present in the one row. To calculate occurrences in the total file, use sum function.

```
from pyspark.context import SparkContext
from pyspark.sql.context import SQLContext
from pyspark.sql.session import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import sum, col, size, split
   
sc = SparkContext()
sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)
spark = SparkSession(sc)
base_df = spark.read.text("/content/fsm-20210817.logs")

server_list = ['nginx-ingress-controller-5b6697898-zqxl4','cert-manager-5695c78d49-q9s9j']

for i in server_list:

    base_df_with_count = base_df.withColumn(i+"count", size(split(col("column_name"), i)) - 1)
    res = base_df_with_count.select(sum(i+"count")).collect()[0][0]
    print(i,res)
```

PS: Not tested the code, but should work.